# Xpath to return all h2 nodes starting from the nth

Tags: xpath

I have several h2 elements on a page, the xpath result should be an array of h2 elements, exluding the first n h2 elements.

```
<div>
    <h2>1</h2>
    <h2>2</h2>
    <h2>3</h2>
</div>
....
<div>
    <h2>4</h2>
    <h2>5</h2>
    ...
    <h2>n<h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Show the actual XML, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this concisely is:

```
(//h2)[position() > n]
```

or

```
(//h2)[position() > n and position() < last() - m]
```

to bound them on both sides. The parentheses around `//h2` make a drastic difference here.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't specific enough for precise answer, but the idea is, you can use `position()` filter to get all `<h2>` elements except those in `position` less than `n`.

For example, assuming that `n` is `1`, you can do as follow :

```
//h2[position()>1]
```

Given this simple structured XML input :

```
<root>
    <h2>1</h2>
    <h2>2</h2>
    <h2>3</h2>
</root>
```

Above XPath will return these elements :

```
<h2>2</h2>
<h2>3</h2>
```

Comment: Is this specific to xpath 2.0 ? Because when I test this in Google Chrome console like this I get nothing. `$x("//h2[position()>3]")`

Comment: This is not XPath 2.0-specific, but it is incorrect. This will only work as described if all of the `h2` elements are under the same parent.

Comment: @JLRishe You're right, that's because there wasn't any context at the time this answer posted, until sample markup added in question about 18 minutes ago

Comment: @har07 That's a fair point, but when someone says they have "several h2 elements on a page", as the question said when it was originally posted, and still does, it's wise not to assume that they all share a common parent.

Answer (score 0):

```
//h2[position() > n]
```

of course replace n with whatever actual value you want...

Answer (score 0):

Found the correct answer, which works for me:

```
//descendant::h2[position()>n
```

And if I want to get m elements after nth element, then

```
//descendant::h2[position()>n and position()<last()-m]
```

Comment: Please see my example for a shorter way to do this. With regards to your approach here, the slash at the beginning is unneeded in both cases.